# float:left breaking with multiple rows of images

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm having a problem with a single page on a website:
http://www.modernprints.co.uk/artist/eduardo-paolozzi

[image: screenshot of problem]

Below 'Eduardo Paolozzi prints for sale' there should be six images as two rows of three, but for some reason it's creating three rows. This only happens when there are more than 3 images, i.e. more than one row. A normal page (i.e. http://www.modernprints.co.uk/artist/lynn-chadwick) looks something like this:

[image: screenshot of normal page]

Strangely, the section below this doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem even though the css is pretty much the same.

It's the same in chrome, ie and firefox.

Comment: looks like a simple clearfix problem. Remember to clear after using multiple floats. Or use display inline in stead.

Comment: clearfix does fix the problem but it doesn't explain why the problem is happening only in the top section and not the bottom one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises because some of your floated elements have slightly different heights, 125px versus 123px.

If you look at your `.thumb-small` elements, sometimes you add the `.new-overlay` element 
that you position using relative positioning, and this causes an extra 2px to be added to
the height of the `.thumb-small` element, which causes the floats to "skip-a-step" so to speak.

One of way of fixing this is to modify your CSS as follows:

First, for `.thumb-small` add `position: relative`.

Second, for `.new-overlay`, use `position: absolute` instead of `position:relative` and
adjust the offsets accordingly to get the GIF in the upper right corner, `right: 10px` and `top:0` seems to work in Firefox.

Comment: Great, thanks. I knew I should be using absolute positioning and that margin was a hack but I'd forgotten that you need to use position:relative in the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Please use "clear:both" in every 3 images.

```
<style>
  .myclear{
   clear:both;
  }
</style>

<div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">...</div>
<div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">...</div>
<div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">...</div>
<div class = "myclear"></div>
<div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">...</div>
<div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">...</div>
<div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">...</div>
```

or

```
<div>
  <h2 class="printsforsale">Eduardo Paolozzi prints for sale</h2>
  <div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">
  <div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">
  <div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">
  <div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px; clear:both;">
  <div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">
  <div class="thumb-small" style="padding-right:10px;">
</div>
<div style="margin-top:259px; clear:both;">
```

Comment: Thanks that seems to work but why is the same problem not happening in the 'prints in archive' section below this one, which doesn't have the clearfix?

Comment: I guess the second image doesn't have <div class="new-overlay"></div> or the other has <div class="new-overlay"></div> that doesn't need it. Please review your class having "new-overlay".

Comment: The source of the problem is due to how the `.new-overlay` positions the GIF image, please see my post for the fix.  Clearing the floats is a solution but it is good to understand how the problem arises in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you have given

```
.new-overlay {
 height:34px;
 margin: -18px;
}
```